# Рисование нескольких кругов в рандомных местах

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Ребят подскажите кто может. Вопрос в следующем:
1.Нужно реализовать чтобы на экране появлялись круги в рандомном месте. 2.Разных радиусов и не перекрывали друг друга.

При компиляции почему то отображается только один круг.

Создал отдельный файл для View. Вот код который я сотворил:

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

    var number = 1

    while number <= 5 {
        //1. Координаты центра экрана
        let viewMidX = self.bounds.size.height
        let viewMidY = self.bounds.size.width

        //2. Радиус уруга
        let circleWidth = CGFloat(20 + arc4random_uniform(30))
        let circleHeight = circleWidth

        //3. Два рандомных числа
        let randomNumberOne = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(40))
        let randomNumberTwo = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(20))

        //4. Координаты и размеры круга
        let rect = CGRect(x: viewMidX / 3 + randomNumberOne , y: viewMidY / 3 + randomNumberTwo , width: circleWidth, height: circleHeight)

        /**5.
         roundedRect: границы в пределах которых отрисовывает;
         cornerRadius: скгругление углов;
         **/
        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: circleWidth / 2)

        //5. Цвет заливки внутренний круга
        мойЦвет.setFill()
        circlePath.fill()

        //6. Цвет обводки круга
        мойЦвет.setStroke()
        circlePath.stroke()

        number += 1
    }
```

В файле ViewController я делаю этому кругу некоторую анимацию(пульсирует)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //7.
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1)

    //8. Анимация круга и его пульсация
    UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: [.autoreverse, .repeat], animations: {
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.9, y: 0.9)
    }) { finished in
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Swift не знаю, но, казалось бы, `number = 1 ... while number <= 1 { ... number += 1 }` - одна итерация и будет

Comment: ДА нене я изменил на 5, все равно 1 круг

Answer (score 0):

Вот такой вариант возможен.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let kCirclesCount: Int = 5

    var circles: Array<CircleView> = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setup()
    }

    private func setup()
    {
        var frame = calcNextCircleFrame()

        for _ in 1 ... kCirclesCount {
            let circleView = CircleView(frame: frame)
            view.addSubview(circleView)
            circles.append(circleView)

            var nextFrame = calcNextCircleFrame();

            for cv in circles {
                frame = cv.frame

                while frame.intersects(nextFrame) {
                    nextFrame = calcNextCircleFrame()
                }

                frame = nextFrame
            }
        }

        for cv in circles {
            cv.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0)

            UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: [.autoreverse, .repeat], animations: {
                cv.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.9, y: 0.9)
            }) { finished in
            }
        }
    }

    private func calcNextCircleFrame() -> CGRect
    {
        let circleSize = CGFloat(20 + arc4random_uniform(30));
        let x = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.view.frame.size.width - circleSize)))
        let y = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.view.frame.size.height - circleSize)))

        return CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: circleSize, height: circleSize)
    }
}
```

Класс вью

```
class CircleView: UIView {

    let kBorderWidth: CGFloat = 10.0

    override init(frame: CGRect)
    {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect)
    {
        let circleSize = frame.size.width - kBorderWidth;
        let circleRect = CGRect(x: kBorderWidth / 2,
                                y: kBorderWidth / 2,
                                width: circleSize,
                                height: circleSize)

        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: circleRect)
        circlePath.lineWidth = kBorderWidth

        UIColor.gray.setStroke()
        circlePath.stroke()

        UIColor.red.setFill()
        circlePath.fill()
    }

    private func setup()
    {
        backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }

}
```